# Using firebase and AWS for my android project

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, firebase

I am building an android app.I wanted to know if its ok to use both firebase and aws in my project? I will be using firebase to save users login information and I will use aws to save all of their images.So before I proceed to do this I wanted to see if its ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase SDKs don't have any explicit restrictions about what other products you can use in your app.  In general, this should be true for any product.

If you are have a specific problem with some apparent conflict between SDKs, please ask a new question with the code and steps to take that cause an issue.

Comment: Thank you Doug for answering my question. Since you said that "Firebase SDKs don't have any explicit restrictions about what other products you can use in your app. In general, this should be true for any product." I will just proceed. Thank you so much